# Button to call multiple class anchor click events only calls one then gives unhelping error

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

I have written a greasemonkey script to customise the way I browse theawesomer.com. I wanted to have a little button I could click next to the post to store the link in a list so I could copy and paste the list into an email and send it to myself for later viewing. I have an email button in another version of the script which automates this fine, I just removed it from this post as it wasn't relevant.

The problem: I have this 'Remove All' button which should, using a jquery class selector, call the click event handler for each of the elements it finds. The click event removes a link in the list and the associated remove link button (not the 'Remove All' button). However it only removes the top item from the list and then throws an error saying 'Component not found' but doesn't point to a line in my code. Can anyone help me find out what is going wrong and how to fix it?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           TheAwesomerLaterLink
// @namespace      theawesomer
// @include        http://theawesomer.com/*
// @include        http://www.theawesomer.com/*
// @require        https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

function addStyle(style)
{
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var element = head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
    element.innerHTML = style;
    return element;    
}

function createLinkInList(link, thisElement) // link = original link/buy anchor, thisElement = this post's new anchor (add button)
{
    var removeButton = $(document.createElement('img'))
                        .attr('src', 'http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/removeButton.png')
                        .attr('title', 'Remove LaterLink')
                        .attr('alt', 'Remove LaterLink')
                        .css(
                        {
                            width: '16px',
                            heigth: '16px',
                            float: 'right'
                        });

    var removeLink = $(document.createElement('a'))
                    .addClass('removeLink')
                    .attr('rel', link.parents('.post').attr('id'))
                    .attr('title', 'Remove LaterLink')
                    .css('cursor', 'pointer')
                    .append(removeButton)
                    .click(function(e)
                    {
                        GM_log('start');
                        e.preventDefault();

                        // Restore add button if on same page still
                        if($('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).length > 0)
                        {
                            var laterLink = $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).find('.LaterLink');
                            laterLink.find('img').attr('src', 'http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/addButton.png');
                            laterLink.unbind('click').click(function(e2)
                            {
                                e2.preventDefault();
                                createLinkInList(link, laterLink);
                            });
                        }

                        // Remove from list of links
                        $(this).parent().remove();
                        GM_log('end');
                    });

    var itemLink = $(document.createElement('a'))
                   .addClass('itemLink')
                   .text(link.parent().prev('h2').find('a').text())
                   .attr('href', link.attr('href'));

    var span = $(document.createElement('span'))
                    .append(itemLink)
                    .append(removeLink)
                    .append($(document.createElement('br')));

    $('#laterLinkList').append(span);

    $(thisElement).find('img').attr('src', 'http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/disabledButton.png');

    $(thisElement).unbind('click');
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Create Links
    $('.post .topmeta a').each(function()
    {
        var link = $(this);
        if(link.attr('title') == 'Link' || link.attr('title') == 'Buy')
        {
            // Track inclusion
            var insertionPoint = $(this).parent()
                                        .siblings('.metabar')
                                        .find('.rightmetabar > span:last');

            // Check if we've already added a link for 'Link' or 'Buy' link
            if(insertionPoint.find('.LaterLink').length == 0)
            {
                newAnchor = $(document.createElement('a'))
                            .attr('rel', link.attr('href'))
                            .attr('class', 'LaterLink')
                            .attr('title', 'LaterLink')
                            .css('cursor', 'pointer')
                            .click(function(e)
                            {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                createLinkInList(link, this);
                            });

                newImage = $(document.createElement('img'))
                            .addClass('icon')
                            .attr('src', 'http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/addButton.png')
                            .attr('title', 'LaterLink')
                            .attr('alt', 'LaterLink')
                            .css(
                            {
                                width: '16px',
                                height: '16px',
                                marginRight: '3px'
                            });

                newAnchor.append(newImage);

                // Put link in metabar next to other share links
                insertionPoint.prepend(newAnchor);
            }
        }
    });

    // Create List
    var panel = $('<div id="actionPanel"><div class="tab"><ul class="tabUL"><li class="left">&nbsp;</li><li id="toggle"><a id="open" class="open">LinkLater</a><a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close">Close</a></li><li class="right">&nbsp;</li></ul></div><div id="actionPanelContent"><div class="content clearfix"><input id="removeAll" type="button" value="Remove All" /><div id="laterLinkList" class="left"></div></div></div></div>');

    // Attach panel to body
    $(document.body).not('iframe body').append(panel);

    // Attach 'remove all' function
    $('#removeAll').css({margin: '0 15px', float: 'right'})
                    .click(function(e)
                    {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('.removeLink').click();
                        return false;
                    });

    // Expand Panel
    $("#open").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#actionPanelContent").slideDown("fast");
    });    

    // Collapse Panel
    $("#close").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#actionPanelContent").slideUp("fast");
    });

    // Switch button from "Open" to "Close" on click
    $("#toggle a").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#toggle a").toggle();
    });

    // Apply stylesheet to panel
    addStyle('@import "http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/TheAwesomerLaterLink.css";');
});
```

Comment: This is a bit much to code-review (A glance does not show the problem).  The question, as-is, would be "Too localized".  Break it down into the smallest example, you can, that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: This is about as small as I could make it and still have it all functional. The code that creates the interface is required to view the list. I would ask people to install it in their greasemonkey add on and visit theawesomer.com to test it out. You will quickly see by adding more than one link to your list and them clicking 'remove all' how the error works. Then just have a look at the event handler code.

Comment: Ambrosia: Paul from The Awesomer here. Just curious - is the "Email" icon under to each post too inconvenient for what you're trying to accomplish? I know you can only send one link at a time, but it does automatically email you (or a friend) the post that you clicked on.

Comment: Wow, I feel a little special gaining the attention of the owner of The Awesomer (among many other great sites). My situation is this: When I browse your website I usually find 10 or more awesome links I really want to check out later (often spanning many pages). However, when I get home the last thing I want to do is have to open 10+ emails to simply get a link from each one. With a little spare time at work I set out to optimise my browsing experience and wrote this link list that worked with a single email. (continued below)

Comment: I haven't published it on userscripts.org and nor do I intend to (especially seeing as how it's referencing external css and images only available on my web server so as to fit with the style of the website). The email link might be used by more casual visitors who may only be interested in one or two links, however every damn link seems so interesting I just have to check them all out! Thanks for your comment Paul and a massive thank you for your creations, keep up the awesome work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised code acheives what I want. Instead of removing the 'add link' from the page I simply change the image to look disabled. Then upon removing the links from the list I just change every 'add link' image to look enabled again and empty the list. Seeing as how I'll be the only one using it this fits fine. Sorry to see the multiple click events couldn't be worked out though. For anyone else interested in this script here it is. I added a localStorage utility that enables list persistence through page changes. You'll need to write your own email script if you want to use that feature though.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           TheAwesomerLaterLink
// @namespace      theawesomer
// @include        http://*theawesomer.com/*
// @require        https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

if(window.top == window.self) // prevent other frames using this script
{
    function addStyle(style)
    {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var element = head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
        element.innerHTML = style;
        return element;
    }

    function hidePopup()
    {
        $('.disabledPopup').hide(500, function()
        {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }

    function showPopup(message)
    {
        // if already visible then dont add a new one
        if($('.disabledPopup').length == 0)
        {
            var element = $(document.createElement('div'))
                            .addClass('disabledPopup')
                            .html(message)
                            .css(
                            {
                                background: '#555',
                                position: 'fixed',
                                top: '10px',
                                right: '10px',
                                padding: '10px',
                                color: 'white',
                                fontWeight: 'bold'
                            })
                            .hide()
                            .bind('click', function()
                            {
                                hidePopup();
                            })
                            .appendTo('body')
                            .show(500, function()
                            {
                                setTimeout(hidePopup, 5000);
                            });
        }
    }

    function createLinkInList(link, thisElement) // link = original link/buy anchor, thisElement = this post's new anchor (add button)
    {
        var removeButton = $(document.createElement('img'))
                            .attr('src', 'http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/removeButton.png')
                            .attr('title', 'Remove LaterLink 1')
                            .attr('alt', 'Remove LaterLink 1')
                            .css(
                            {
                                width: '20px',
                                heigth: '20px',
                                float: 'right'
                            });

        var removeLink = $(document.createElement('a'))
                        .addClass('removeLink')
                        .attr('rel', link.parents('.post').attr('id'))
                        .attr('title', 'Remove LaterLink 2')
                        .css({cursor: 'pointer', marginLeft:'10px'})
                        .append(removeButton)
                        .click(function(e)
                        {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            // Restore add button if on same page still
                            if($('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).length > 0)
                            {
                                var laterLink = $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).find('.LaterLink');
                                laterLink.find('img').attr('src', 'http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/addButton.png');
                            }

                            // Remove from list of links
                            $(this).parent().remove();
                        });

        var itemLink = $(document.createElement('a'))
                       .addClass('itemLink')
                       .text(link.parent().prev('h2').find('a').text())
                       .attr('href', link.attr('href'));

        var span = $(document.createElement('span'))
                        .append(itemLink)
                        .append(removeLink)
                        .append($(document.createElement('br')))
                        .append($(document.createElement('br')));

        $('#laterLinkList').append(span);

        $(thisElement).find('img').attr('src', 'http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/disabledButton.png');
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        // Create Links
        $('.post .topmeta a').each(function()
        {
            var link = $(this);
            if(link.attr('title') == 'Link' || link.attr('title') == 'Buy')
            {
                // Track inclusion
                var insertionPoint = $(this).parent()
                                            .siblings('.metabar')
                                            .find('.rightmetabar > span:last');

                // Check if we've already added a link for 'Link' or 'Buy' link
                if(insertionPoint.find('.LaterLink').length == 0)
                {
                    newAnchor = $(document.createElement('a'))
                                .attr('rel', link.attr('href'))
                                .attr('class', 'LaterLink')
                                .attr('title', 'LaterLink')
                                .css('cursor', 'pointer')
                                .click(function(e)
                                {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    createLinkInList(link, this);
                                });

                    newImage = $(document.createElement('img'))
                                .addClass('icon')
                                .addClass('LaterLinkIcon')
                                .attr('src', 'http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/addButton.png')
                                .attr('title', 'LaterLink')
                                .attr('alt', 'LaterLink')
                                .css(
                                {
                                    width: '16px',
                                    height: '16px',
                                    marginRight: '3px'
                                });

                    newAnchor.append(newImage);

                    // Put link in metabar next to other share links
                    insertionPoint.prepend(newAnchor);
                }
            }
        });

        // Create List
        var panel = $('<div id="actionPanel"><div class="tab"><ul class="tabUL"><li class="left">&nbsp;</li><li id="toggle"><a id="open" class="open">LinkLater</a><a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close">Close</a></li><li class="right">&nbsp;</li></ul></div><div id="actionPanelContent"><div class="content clearfix"><div style="float:right;width:145px;text-align:left;"><a id="emailList" style="background:url(http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/bt_email.png) no-repeat left 0;cursor:pointer;padding-left:20px;">Email List</a><br/><br/><a id="removeAll" style="background:url(http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/bt_close.png) no-repeat left 0;padding-left:20px;cursor:pointer;">Remove All</a></div><div id="laterLinkList" class="left"></div></div></div></div>');

        // Attach panel to body
        $(document.body).not('iframe body').append(panel);

        // Attach 'remove all' function
        $('#removeAll').hover(function()
                        {
                            $(this).css('background', 'url(http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/bt_close.png) no-repeat left -19px');

                        }, function()
                        {
                            $(this).css('background', 'url(http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/bt_close.png) no-repeat left 0');

                        }).click(function(e)
                        {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#laterLinkList').empty();
                            $('.LaterLinkIcon').attr('src', 'http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/addButton.png')
                        });

        $('#emailList').hover(function()
                        {
                            $(this).css('background', 'url(http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/bt_email.png) no-repeat left -19px');

                        }, function()
                        {
                            $(this).css('background', 'url(http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/bt_email.png) no-repeat left 0');

                        }).click(function(e)
                        {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            //showPopup('email');

                            $.ajax(
                            {
                                url: '<removed>',
                                type: 'post',
                                data: {content: $('a.itemLink').serializeArray()},
                                complete: function(e, XHR, options)
                                {
                                    if (XHR.status == 403)
                                    {
                                        showPopup('forbidden');
                                    }
                                },
                                success: function(response)
                                {
                                    showPopup(response);
                                }
                            });
                        });

        // Expand Panel
        $("#open").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#actionPanelContent").slideDown("fast");
        }); 

        // Collapse Panel
        $("#close").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#actionPanelContent").slideUp("fast");
        });

        // Switch button from "Open" to "Close" on click
        $("#toggle a").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#toggle a").toggle();
        });

        // Apply stylesheet to panel
        addStyle('@import "http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/TheAwesomerLaterLink.css";');

        // add on unload function so can save the list before user changes pages maybe?

        $(unsafeWindow).unload(function()
        {
            var list = $('#laterLinkList').html();
            unsafeWindow.localStorage.setItem('LaterLinks', list);
        });

        // Preload existing links
        var list = unsafeWindow.localStorage.getItem('LaterLinks');
        if(list != '')
        {
            $('#laterLinkList').html($(list));

            // setup removeLink events again
            $('.removeLink').click(function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();

                // Restore add button if on same page still
                if($('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).length > 0)
                {
                    var laterLink = $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).find('.LaterLink');
                    laterLink.find('img').attr('src', 'http://alphadesigns.com.au/greasemonkey/addButton.png');
                }

                // Remove from list of links
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the JQuery .click() method to be unreliable when I need some sort of auto-clicking behavior, but the .mousedown() method seems to always work. Unfortunately, the website you are monkeying might not be listening for onmousedown.

It's also a difference in browsers. If I recall correctly, Safari on a PC handles .click() okay, for instance, but not Safari on a Mac.

**UPDATE** Maybe it's a timing issue - try something like a timeout before you call the click method:

```
$('.removeLink').each(function () {
    window.setTimeout('removeIt("' + this.id + '")',10);
});
function removeIt(id) {
    $('#' + id).click();
}
```

Comment: the click handler is one I wrote in the script as well, not one already on the page

Comment: Try changing it to mousedown then - that should work if it's the same as my autoclick problem!

Comment: Tried, doesn't change a thing.

Comment: I would think, then, that executing .click on a selector that returns more than one element is the problem. try: $('.removeLink').each(function() { $(this).click(); });

Comment: I already tried that too. Still the same error. Sorry, perhaps I should have mentioned that in the initial post.

Comment: That was my best guess o_O. I would just start trial and error, create individual id='' attributes for the elements instead of just being members of the removeLink class, execute two inline that I know of, maybe put the click() call into a setTimeout call in case it was a timing issue. It took me quite a while to figure out my auto click problem - did you try using .each() with .mousedown() ?

Comment: Nup, just tried... what I think I will just have to do is change the 'add' button to 'disabled' but dont remove the add event handler and then just empty the list with 'remove all'. I really want to figure out a solution to this so I will leave it up here until I decide there is no better alternative and post my work around.

Answer (score 0):

Calling all the `removeLink` clicks via jQuery is not the same as clicking the links individually.  You must pay extra attention to the `this` scope/object and to the event object.

Ideally, the code should be refactored, but the easy fix -- inline with the question's title -- is to send actual click events.  To do that, replace:

```
$('.removeLink').click();
```

with:

```
$('.removeLink').each ( function() {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ("HTMLEvents");
    clickEvent.initEvent ("click", true, true);
    this.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
} );
```